# apt update related

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, repository, 21.04

Yesterday I gave a command `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and after that every time I do `sudo apt update`, these lines come up.

`sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Is there any way I can revert?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of windows with text outputs. Just copy the output, and paste it into the question.

Comment: okay, done. Now can you help?

Comment: Your sources are misconfigured. Please edit your question and add the complete output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. Please use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to retain line breaks and formatting so we can parse the info.

Comment: Thanks a lot @N0bert